# Unix join command not working for me

Tags: linux, unix

I have a homework assignment that says make a file and put this data in it

```
Brown:82:53,000
Anders:110:32,000
Caplan:174:41,000
Crow:95:36,000
```

I called this empsal

And then another file called empname which contains

```
Brown:LaVerne:F:Accounting Department:444-7508: . . .
Anders:Carol:M:Sales Department:444-2130: . . .
Caplan:Jason:R:Payroll Department:444-5609: . . .
Crow:Lorretta:L:Shipping Department:444-8901: . . .
```

I have to use the join command to join these files and make the output, called empbud, look like this.

```
Brown:LaVerne:Accounting Department:53,000
Anders:Carol:Sales Department:32,000
Caplan:Jason:Payroll Department:41,000
Crow:Lorretta:Shipping Department:36,000
```

So I tried using the command like this

```
join -1 1 3 -2 1 2 4 empsal empname > empbud
```

I want to join the last name and the salary from empsal, and the first name and the department and the salary from empname.

Comment: `man join` and look for the `-o` (output) option. You're almost there. Good luck.

Comment: I tried 
`join -1 1 3 -2 1 2 4 empsal empname -o empfinal`

and it said extra operand 4

Comment: and also remeber to sort the input files: and you will need to look at the `-t` option as well

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/join.html Look at the `-o` option here. `-o` does NOT mean `output`. Opps, yes, and sort your input! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `-o FORMAT` specification:

```
join -j 1 -t : -o 2.1,2.2,2.4,1.3 empsal empname
```

**Output**

```
Brown:LaVerne:Accounting Department:53,000
Anders:Carol:Sales Department:32,000
Caplan:Jason:Payroll Department:41,000
Crow:Lorretta:Shipping Department:36,000
```

The command breaks down as follows:

```
join -j 1 -t :
```

Join files on `field 1` with field separator `:` The input files must be in sort order on the field to be joined. Then the format specifier:

```
-o 2.1,2.2,2.4,1.3
```

Provides output containing `file2:field1` `file2:field2` `file2:field4` `file1:field3`

Comment: ... and for sorted input files.